# MongoDB Client disconnects when I open another connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nrwl-nx

I have an Nx project where I have two apps. Both connect to a different MongoDB instance like this:

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, {
    keepAlive: true,
});

await mongoClient.connect();
await mongoClient.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
logger.info(`Connected to MongoDB at ${url}`);
```

My problem is that if I start one of the services it runs perfectly, but if I start the other one (which has the same code for connecting, but tries to connect to a different MongoDB instance) the other service disconnects!

What am I doing wrong? I need both services to connect to their own MongoDB instance.

This is what I'm getting:

```
MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation
```

and I'm running both services as a standalone node.js app with Nx:

```
nx serve projectA
nx serve projectB
```